# RegEx Extract numbers between two under scores google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Hey I'm looking for help extracting the `130` from the below string

```
Image_320*50e+SaleImages_NA_washing-SALE-11/30/20_130_NA_NA____
```

I have made the below formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A5, "_[0-9]+/*")
```

But my result is this `_130`

I only want to see `130`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A5, "_([0-9]+)/*")
```

The parenthesis form a "capture group" that returns only what is inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Lance. It didn't strictly need all of the elements you had, but since you wrote it and were familiar with what you wrote, I left it like you had it originally except for that addition of the capture group. Figured it would make most sense to you. If this does satisfy your request, please take a moment to mark the answer "Best Answer" so that other contributors know the "case is closed," and so that future site visitors can quickly find the answers that best match their needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not quite clear to me whether you are looking for `130` or `320`.
Here is a solution for each.

To get `130` use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT($A$5, "_([0-9]+)_")
```

To get `320` use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT($A$5, "([0-9]+)")
```

[image]